# localhost is showing index of when I added a virtual host in /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, webserver, virtualhost

I installed apache with brew and changed port `8080` to `80`. when I accessed `localhost` this shown me a page "it works!" and that page is located in `/usr/local/var/www` directory with file name index.html but when I added a virtual host in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/ranaamir/projects/sample/yii2/backend/web"
  ServerName yii2.example.be
  ServerAlias yii2.example.be
  <directory "/Users/ranaamir/projects/sample/yii2/backend/web">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </directory>
  ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/vjfBackenderror.log"
  CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/vjfBackendaccess.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart the service with `sudo apachectl -k restart` command and this host also added in `/etc/hosts`.

```
##

127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       yii2.example.be
```

Then I access `localhost` or `yii2.example.be` both are showing a page where only one line mentioned `Index of /`.

if I remove code of block `<VirtualHost *:80>` from `httpd-vhosts.conf` then again `localhost` host showing correct `index.html`.

why my project not running on the virtual-host url instead of `index of /`?

Any help would be so appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, I made little change in `httpd.conf` file where we have to mentioned which type of file they will be process first so I just added `index.php` in the code block of `dir_module`.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

I hope this will save your time and minimize your stress. :)